# Почему не работают условия в PHP?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день!

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему не срабатывают условия?

Необходимо в тексте найти все буквы «a»:

1. Если буква «a» стоит между двух букв «b» - вот так: «bab», то нужно заключить её в тег `<b>`, вот так: `b<b>a</b>b`;
2. Если буква «a» не стоит между двумя «b» (не подходит под первое условие), то ТОЛЬКО ТОГДА заключить её в тег `<i>` - вот так: `<i>a</i>`.

Это сильно-сильно упрощенная, необходимая мне конструкция, поэтому её необходимо сделать именно с помощью if else.

Что делаю я:

```
// ищем в тексте, поочереди, все буквы «а»
if ( preg_match( "/a/miu", $text ) ) {

  // далее поверяем, находится ли буква «a», между двух букв «b»
  if ( preg_match( "/bab/miu", $text ) ) {
    // если условие верно, то заключаем её в тег <b>
    $text = preg_replace( "/bab/miu", "b<b>a</b>b", $text );
  // во всех остальных случаях...
  } else {
    // заключаем её в тег <i>
    $text = preg_replace( "/a/miu", "<i>a</i>", $text );
  }

}
```

Почему-то, срабатывает только первая часть условия, вот это:

```
  // далее поверяем, находится ли буква «a», между двух букв «b»
  if ( preg_match( "/bab/miu", $text ) ) {
    // если условие верно, то заключаем её в тег <b>
    $content = preg_replace( "/bab/miu", "b<b>a</b>b", $text );
  }
```

А вторая часть никогда не срабатывает, вот эта:

```
 else {
    // заключаем её в тег <i>
    $content = preg_replace( "/a/miu", "<i>a</i>", $text );
  }
```

Почему? И как заставить её работать?..

Двумя словами задачу можно описать так: отделить букву а, которая не находится между букв б.

Comment: ` `  через апострофы вставляйте

Answer (score 1):

Тупо и в лоб:

```
/* 1: меняем bab на b<b>a</b>b */
$text = str_replace( 'bab', 'b<b>a</b>b', $text );
/* 2: меняем a, которая не внутри тегов, на <i>a</i> */
$text = preg_replace( '/([^>])a([^<])/miu', '$1<i>a</i>$2', $text );
```

Comment: `/* 2: меняем a, которая не внутри тегов, на <i>a</i> */` вы меняете не `а`, а любые три символа (отличных от `>a<`) центральный из которых `а` такой регуляркой `/[^>]a[^<]/miu`. Регулярка у вас не верная. Или замена.

Comment: А, ну да, глюканул :) Сейчас поправлю.

Comment: Тупо и в лоб не получится... Для примера, попробуйте расставить тег <br> во всех пустых строках, кроме тех, которые находятся внутри тега <pre>.

Comment: @PavelV, не дело додумывать вопрос за автора. Но я исхожу их того, что нужный текст или существует сам по себе, уже вытащен из DOM. * `попробуйте расставить тег <br> во всех пустых строках, кроме тех, которые находятся внутри тега <pre>`* - даже пытаться не буду.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю воспользоваться функцией `preg_replace_callback` и регулярным выражением `'~bab|(a)~'`, которое найдет все `bab` и `a`, захватывая `a` в подмаску №1. Внутри анонимного метода провереям, есть ли текст в буфере первой подмаски и производим соответствующие замены.

```
$s = "sas bab aaa";
$res = preg_replace_callback('~bab|(a)~', function($m) {
    if (isset($m[1]) && !empty($m[1])) {
        return "<i>".$m[1]."</i>";
    } else {
        return "b<b>a</b>b";
    }
}, $s);
echo $res;
```

[См. онлайн PHP-демо](https://ideone.com/d5Nz6P).

Answer (score -1):

вообще не нужна тут регулярка

```
if(strpos($text,'a')) {
    if(strpos($text,'bab')) { 
        $text = str_replace('bab','b<b>a</b>b',$text);
    } else {
        $text = str_replace('a','<i>a</i>',$text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Берём текст `'sas bab aaa'`, и что получаем?

Comment: Попробуйте расставить тег <br> во всех пустых строках, кроме тех, которые находятся внутри тега <pre>.

Comment: `strpos` может вернуть как `false`, так и `0`